# Why can not run this code in the local machine System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"\\path\file.bat");

Tags: c#, iis

I have this code

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"\\path\file.bat");
```

When I run in the page (http://localhost:63807/Upload.aspx) the code works correctly.
But when I run in  another machine (http://myhostname/Upload.aspx) the code does not work correctly. It does not execute the `\\path\file.bat`

Could you help me with this problem ?

Comment: Try execute `File.Exists(@"\path\file.bat");` on your local and other machine

Comment: i am try this in the file exist

Comment: Does your iis have the read access to load that file in other machine?

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) for IIS Application Pool identities and permissions. You can compare these between your 2 machines.

Comment: use sysinternals procmon to see the filesystem call and the result